# Display Full Month Name

Tags: templating, entries, datetime

Currently trying to get the date filter to display 'April' instead of concatenated version 'Apr'. My code below is:

```
{{ now|date("M, Y") }}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using this.

```
{{ now|date("F, Y") }}
```

You can find the format strings for the date filter: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php